# How to select Yes/No field in MS Access (I get an error)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007, oledb

Right now I have this code:

```
 Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select 1stShift as [First Shift] from &_ 
 EmployeeDesignation where EmployeeID= '" & empID & "' and &_
 DesignationDate= '" & day & "'", DBConnection)
```

I get an error "*Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '1stShift'.*"

But if I change 1stShift to EmployeeID, or DesignationDate, which are both "Text" fields, it works just fine.

Please enlighten me. Thank you!

Comment: Put square brackets around that field name.

Comment: What is `1stShift` a a table or column or what? Is that your actual SQL?  You should be using parameters to avoid SQL injection attacks, and errors from certain strings, and more readable SQL.  And your question seems to have nothing to do with the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming 1stShift is a valid column name this should work

```
 Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select [1stShift] as [First Shift] from " &_ 
 "EmployeeDesignation where EmployeeID= '" & empID & "' and "&_
 "DesignationDate= '" & day & "'", DBConnection)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try putting `1stShift` in square brackets:

```
"Select [1stShift] . . . "
```

Many databases don't allow regular identifiers to begin with a number.  If so, then it is expecting an operator after the number (of some sort) which might be generating the error.